# Passing array to Controller asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my application using JQuery, I'm collecting data in the table and passing it to an array.

Then I want to save that values on my database.

In the controller, it shows the count of data that passed. But inside is empty. Not sure that the variable is right. Can you help me with this?

This is the JQuery code

```
function createOrder() {

  const Orders = $("#tblParts tbody tr").filter(function() {
    const cells = $(this).find("td");
    return cells.eq(8).text().trim() != ""
  }).map(function() {
    const cells = $(this).find("td");
    return { [cells.eq(0).text().trim()] : +cells.eq(8).text()
    }
  }).get()

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/InsertOrder",
    data: JSON.stringify(Orders),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(r) {
      alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
    }
  });
}
```

This is the controller,

```
  public JsonResult InsertOrder(List<string> Orders)
  {

  }
```

I'm not sure about this `List<string> Orders` I called it correctly?

Editing

This is the array data

[image]

This is from the controller side.

[image]

HTML Code

```
<table class="table" id="tblParts">
  <tr>
    <th> @Html.DisplayName("Part Number") </th>
    <th> @Html.DisplayName("Part Description") </th>
    <th> @Html.DisplayName("Model") </th>
    <th> @Html.DisplayName("Stock Available") </th>
    <th> @Html.DisplayName("Re-Order Qty") </th>
    <th> @Html.DisplayName("Part Category") </th>
    <th> @Html.DisplayName("ABCD Category") </th>
    <th> @Html.DisplayName("New Order Qty") </th>
    <th></th>
  </tr> @foreach (var item in Model.RecognizedPartsViewModel) { <tr>
    <td style="display:none;"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id) </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PartNo)
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model)
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AvaQty)
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReOrderQty)
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#"> @if (PartCategory.Exists(x => x.Value == item.PartCato.ToString())) { @PartCategory.Find(x => x.Value == item.PartCato.ToString()).Text }
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ABCD)
    </td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr> }
</table>
```

Comment: show the content of 'data' (the json you are sending)

Comment: What exactly you want to pass to the controller from given example? you want to pass whole object or just value like : `15 and 21`

Comment: Your controller is accepting `List<string>` but from the JS, it seems like you're sending an `object`. You will either have to change your JS or C# code accordingly

Comment: Try to provide html as well,

Comment: @KiranJoshi Actually I'm adding ID and Qty to the array and passing them to the controller

Comment: @KiranJoshi I want to pass `43 and 15 ` `115 and 21` accordingly.  Those are the Id and the Qty. So I want to save it on the database.

Comment: @KiranJoshi  I have added the HTML code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a very strange array that is not valid in c#. So try to use a dictionary as an action parameter

```
public JsonResult InsertOrder([FromBody]Dictionary<int,int>[] Orders)
```

it will be working but it is a very strange format. IMHO convert javascript data to something more easier to use.

```
var newOrders = $.map(Orders, function (element) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var key in element) {
    obj.Id = key;
    obj.Quantity = element[key];
   }
  return obj;
});
```

create class

```
public class IdQ
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int Quantity {get; set;}
}
```

and action

```
public JsonResult InsertOrder([FromBody]List<IdQ> idQs)
```

Comment: This method worked

Answer (score 0):

I just convert object to key value pair array

```
function createOrder() {

  const Orders = $("#tblParts tbody tr").filter(function() {
    const cells = $(this).find("td");
    return cells.eq(8).text().trim() != ""
  }).map(function() {
    const cells = $(this).find("td");
    return { [cells.eq(0).text().trim()] : +cells.eq(8).text()
    }
  }).get()
var result = Object.keys(Orders).map((key) => [Number(key), obj[key]]);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/InsertOrder",
    data: JSON.stringify(result),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(r) {
      alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
    }
  });
}
```

Conroller:

```
public JsonResult InsertOrder(Dictionary<int,int> Orders)
  {

  }
```

So now you can access your data in controller using above changes.

Comment: didn't worked this as well

Comment: @DevBeginner have you tried updated code?

Comment: I updated your code with mine. There I got an error with the `obj`. The error shows as obj not defined. The somehow previous solution was worked. Thanks, @kiranjoshi for the support. Cheers.